# How are the primary keys in Phoenix are converted as row keys in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

Phoenix Query:

```
CREATE TABLE STORE.DETAILS (Market UNSIGNED_INT NOT NULL, Product UNSIGNED_INT NOT NULL, Period UNSIGNED_INT NOT NULL, Units double CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (Market_Key, Product_Key, Period_Key))
```

In hbase i am having just having two columns i hope Primary key combination is converted to row key.

Can you please let me know how the primary keys are combined and converted to rowkeys in Phoenix?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the primary key is considered as the row key and phoenix uses a default delimiter(zero byte) to separate the row key when you have more than one column as primary key. Everything in hbase is stored as byte array, and when you retrieve it with client API use the appropriate type which you used during your UPSERT or put to get the row key back.

Comment: If the phoenix table is salted you might see a prefix in the row key corresponding to the salting.